# Save jpg image to mongodb using gridfs with python and retrieve it from database when needed

Tags: python, mongodb, gridfs

I'm trying to save jpg image to mongodb using gridfs with python and retrieve it from database when needed. It looks like it saves fine, then I store its `fileid` in collection and when reading I use it to locate the image. But it deosn't give me back the image I saved before.

Here is the class definition:

```
class dbase():
    database=""

def __init__(self,dbserver,dbport ):
    from pymongo import MongoClient

    client =MongoClient()
    self.database = client['test']

def Savetodb(self,event):
    import gridfs
    import tkMessageBox
    result = tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Save to db???", "Confirm Save")
    if result:
    # get image name and image file from the widget box
        filename=event.widget.cget("text")
        img =event.widget.cget("image")
        fs = gridfs.GridFS(self.database)
        fileid = fs.put(img,filename=filename)
        self.database.my_collection.insert_one({"imagefile":filename,"fileid":fileid})


def Getfromdb(self,outfilename):
    import gridfs
    fs = gridfs.GridFS(self.database)
    fid = ""

    for item in self.database.my_collection.find({"imagefile":outfilename}):
        fid=item["fileid"]
    if fid <> "":
        outputdata = fs.get(fid).read()
        return outputdata
```

Comment: Why do you have `import` statements in your `class` and `methods`?

Comment: this is only a test module, just trying things out different way.

Comment: Are "imagefile" values unique in my_collection? Your code looks like it could be correct, but perhaps there are multiple images with the same "imagefile".

Comment: imagefile is unique and it does return the saved image as it seems like but when trying to assign it to a Label image, it gives me error:

Comment: File "./python/eng.py", line 80, in Addbox
    widget = Label(canvas,text=self.text,image=myimg)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2587, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2086, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist